# Statusbar overlapping on UIImagepickercontroller's Camera View in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8, statusbar, overlapping

im using UIImagepickercontroller to take photo and choose existing photos, when the camera   view appears, the top portion on camera was covered by the white status bar. How can i remove the status bar or hide the status bar. Many of them saying its a ios 7 bug, it has been fixed in ios 7.1, but still i'm facing this problem.

This is my code to show the imagepickerController

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = (id)self;
imagePicker.sourceType = (buttonIndex == actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex ?  

UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary);
[self.viewController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also i tried by with below codes to hide statusbar

```
 - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController    
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
   }
```

This

```
 -(BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
   return YES;
 }
```

And This in Delegate

```
 [UIApplication ShareApplication]SetStatusbarHidden:YES];
```

Right now i'm working with ios8, and this behaviour happening in all ios version. 
Please help me out.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In iOS7 I solved it by subclassing UIImagePickerController and overriding prefersStatusBarHidden to YES. But on iOS8 it just stopped working. If you find a solution, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is in my rootviewcontroller i'm creating a Statusbar using UIView and setting its constraints for landscape and portrait programmatically

```
- (void)setTopBar {
if(topBar == nil && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] != nil) {
    topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
    topBar.backgroundColor = navController.view.backgroundColor;
    topBar.tag = topBarViewTag;
    UIView *containerView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [containerView addSubview:topBar];
    [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view(20)]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil   views:@{@"view" : topBar}]];
    [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil   views:@{@"view" : topBar}]];
    [containerView layoutSubviews];
}
```

}

so when i commented the above method in ViewwillAppear, status bar where not showing up, so the problem is with my code.

if anyone face the same issue, i suggest you to have a look on your RootViewcontroller, which acts a navigation to all other classes.